# Mongodb sort Aggregation in same order ids was passed on filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to know if its possible to keep the current order of the result the same as it is passed in on the filtering.

So lets say we have an array of IDS:

```
var arrayValues = [1,3,2]
```

I would like to aggregate the values but keep the result same order as im passing in the above array.

```
 var result = Item.aggregate([{ $match: { _id: { $in: arrayValues } }}])
```

I would want the result in same order as the array values passed in as `_id` value.

**Example Result :**

```
result = [{ _id: 1 },{ _id: 3 },{ _id: 2 }]
```

Comment: no, it will return the result in the natural order that is present in the collection. I don't think any better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `indexOfArray` for this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: {$in: arrayValues}}},
  {$set: {index: {$indexOfArray: [arrayValues, "$_id"]}}},
  {$sort: {index: 1}},
  {$unset: "index"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k6pUk2398Y3)

Comment: it works for me thanks ! Would you think this is better than doing a map sort afterwards ?

Comment: That depends on your needs and machines since these are different sources...

Comment: Is it possible to do this with `.find`, or only in `.aggregate`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a way of doing it in the query without an aggregation pipeline